# How to access site name from Google search

Tags: web

> I have already hosted my website, and I want to search it from Google.

- How can I search?
- Is there any need to upload my website to Google?

Comment: You'll have to wait until Google notices your website. If you want insight on how the status is, sign up for Google Webmaster Tools.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, at least [webmaster submission](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/submit-url?pli=1). Also, read more about the webmaster tool.

Answer (score 0):

Add the proper search term to your searched words:
site:www.your-website.com searchword

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Google Webmaster tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools) for this purpose. Add your website there and you can get very valuable information about the state of your website on Google.

For faster inclusion of all pages of your website on Google database, you can create a sitemap.xml file (if you do not know how you can create it online [here](https://www.xml-sitemaps.com/)) and add it to Google webmaster tools.

You also can see on the Google page, placing the command "site:" before the url of your website in the search field, to view which pages are already indexed.